# Access Vba Setorderby ASC or DESC with and if

Tags: vba, if-statement

In a form in ACCESS, i want the user to be able to set by ASC and DESC by clicking the same button. My code only sorts by ASC

```
Public Function Tri_par_vehicule()

  If OrderBy = "Véhicules ASC" Then
    DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Véhicules DESC"
  Else
    DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Véhicules ASC"
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it, you want the order to be reversed each time the function is called. You can do this by saving the last value in a static variable:

```
Public Function Tri_par_vehicule()
    Static OrderBy as String
    If OrderBy = "Véhicules ASC" Then
        DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Véhicules DESC"
        OrderBy = "Véhicules DESC"
    Else
        DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Véhicules ASC"
        OrderBy = "Véhicules ASC"
    End If
End Function
```